# Is it possible to index relationship properties

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I know you can create index on node properties, but I could not find if it is possible to do the same on relationship properties. Is it possible with the latest version of neo4j(2.0.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation on automatic indexing. You cannot perform schema indexing on relationship properties but can go for legacy indexing.

refer: [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/auto-indexing.html)